# Ionic / Angularjs Credit Card Scanner

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, card.io

I am looking for something similar to to the card.io library that will work across all the platforms using Ionic.   Right now card.io only works on ios.

Use Case:  User can scan the credit card on iOS, Android, and Windows devices.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So a cordova plugin for card.io is now available. You can integrate a cordova/Phonegap plugin in your Ionic app to provide support for credit card scanning in your app. This will work across multiple platforms. Here's the detail of plugin:

1. [Card-IO iOS SDK Cordova Plugin](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK-PhoneGap)
2. [CARD-IO Android Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/card.io)
3. [CARD-IO Cordova Plugin List](https://github.com/card-io/phonegap-plugins)

Comment: Thanks.  I have seen the list.  Do I need to install these plugins separately and code for them separately?

Comment: You need to install/add iOS plugin to iOS project and Andriod plugin to android project seperately. But a common JS/AngularJS code would work for both of them. This is similar to what we typically do in an hybrid mobile app.

Comment: @JotiBasi did you able to integrated to the ionic app?

Comment: No.  I am still working on it.  My project is taking much longer than originally anticipated.  I had to prioritize other features over this one.

Comment: @N-JOY I have created the app and it works fine with iOS where I had to use watch and apply scope to apply it to the scope in my AngularJS app.  however, when I used it on Android 6.1, I can see the card data captured in the debug using adb logcat and console.log but it doesn't apply it to the view.  Any suggestions?